# Entity breaks with too many predicates (parser stack overflow)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sqlite

In my code I allow the user to filter by a parameter (extensions). There can be quite a lot of different extensions (100+).

Until now I used this:

```
foreach (var i in FilteredExt)
{
    backupEvents = backupEvents.Where(e => (e.Ext != i && e.Ext != "." + i));
}
```

But I noticed that this works if FilteredExt contains small amount of items (~30) - if it contains more the query breaks and the view is left empty.

Error:

> parser stack overflow at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String
>   strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)
>   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand() at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult() at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd,
>   CommandBehavior behave) at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Is there a way to handle/avoid this?

Comment: Any reason the ``FilteredExt`` arent stored in the Database?

Comment: @RandRandom mainly because I never thought about it. You're suggesting adding a new table and updating it everytime user de/selects extensions? I guess this isn't a problem - but how then I get events without FilteredExt ?

Comment: ``var backupevents = context.Events.SqlQuery("select * from events ev where ev.ext not in (select fe.ext from filteredext fe)");`` - dont know how to translate ``not in`` to linq, but you could use it.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I will try to implement this when I have time. I wonder in cases of filtering - does it usually works with saving the filtered list in the DB or do you usually save it in the runtime environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure will it work or not, but can you try to do filtering in that way:

```
var FilteredExtWithDot = FilteredExt.Select(x=>"." + x).ToArray();
backupEvents = 
          backupEvents
          .Where(e => !FilteredExt.Contains(e.Ext) && !FilteredExtWithDot.Contains(e.Ext));
```

and no foreach needed.

Comment: Kinda doubt this will be translated into SQL.

Comment: @RandRandom it will work for SQL Server, but I not sure about SQL Lite

Comment: Thx for the update, didnt know you could pass a local list into it and it translate it correctly.